# awk -- adding a new delimiter to the default space delimiter

Tags: unix, awk

awk default delimiter *space* treats any amount of space between two fields as equivalent..

```
echo "1  2"|awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i}'
#which gives the result (two spaces between 1 and 2)
1
2
```

How can I add "=" to this existing delimiter? I have tried the following and that has started to consider "single" space character as a delimiter and spoiled the above result.

```
 echo "1  2"|awk -F"[ |=]" '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i}'
    #which gives the result
    1

    2
```

How can I give any amount of space as a delimiter here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a regular expression as the delimiter:

```
 echo "1  2"|awk -F"[ |=]+" '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i}'
```

It also means

```
 echo "1  2 3==5"|awk -F"[ |=]+" '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i}'
```

would print

```
1
2
3
5
```

Comment: Wonderful! Yes, I have read about the regular expression for delimiter from an other thread but it seems **+** does the trick here. It is taking care of multiple spaces, multiple "=" signs (very nice example in the second case illustrating both these points, BTW). What exactly does the **+** do here?

Comment: `+` is for *one or more occurrences* of the specified regex. So it would combine multiple delimiters. Another example: `echo "1==|=  2"|awk -F"[|= ]+" '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i}'` would print `1<newline>2<newline>`